# Getting different Ads pop up in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

## selenium webdriver#

i am running this code on selenium webdriver(chromedriver), but the moment , it click add new customer , advertisment popup comes and i am not able to close it- not able to move forward from here. sometime ads has close and sometime ad has  cancel button. can someone help me. waiting for
Answer

```
      driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/");
driver.findElement(By.name("emailid")).sendKeys("ajay@yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr385415");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("regatAm");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Customer")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Close");`enter code here`
```

Comment: I am stuck here, please someone help me

Comment: before going to the website go to chrome / firefox extansions and add adblock. Not the smartest way, but its easy to solve

Comment: i have added it

Comment: if my solution helped you, you can mark it as correctly :)

Comment: Add few try, catch blocks, try if add is visible, and in catch add what action you want to perform if try block fails (which means add is not visible), similarly, add try catch for add close button, let me know if you need some sample code.

Comment: can someone provide me you tube  video/link for the problem ,for every run , a new advertisement window  get  open and script stops there

Answer (score 0):

You can install Adblock automatically with Selenium. I wrote you an example to solve your problem. It then should never pop up an ad anymore. Here is my solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


def adblock():
    driver.get(
        "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=de")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "dd-Va g-c-wb g-eg-ua-Uc-c-za g-c-Oc-td-jb-oa g-c"))).click()
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()


adblock()


def main():
# Your code
```